# How do I set up a stand-alone Gunicorn App server if I already have an Nginx proxy set up?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, gunicorn, devops

I'm trying to set up multiple servers that look like:

```
Client Request ----> Nginx (Reverse-Proxy / Load-Balancer)
                        |
                       /|\                           
                      | | `-> App. Server I.   10.128.xxx.yy1:8080 # Our example
                      |  `--> App. Server II.  10.128.xxx.yy2:8080
                       `----> ..
```

I understand that I need to put the App servers (Gunicorn in this case) behind an Nginx Proxy, but how do I set up the App servers by themselves?

I'm trying to set up the App server with systemd, and my configuration looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=kyle
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/kyle/do_app_one
ExecStart=/home/kyle/do_app_one/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/kyle/do_app_one/do_app_one.sock do_app_one.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I know the socket is being created because I can see it:

[image]

but I can't access the Gunicorn server by itself when I hit the IP address, with or without the :8000 port attached to it. Without the systemd configuration, I can access the site if I do:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application
```

but I want to do this the right way with an init system like systemd, and I don't think I'm supposed to be binding it directly to a port because I've read it's less efficient/secure than using a socket. Unless binding to a port is the only way, then I guess that's what I have to do.

Every tutorial I see says I need an Nginx server in front of my Gunicorn server, but I already have an Nginx server in front of them. Do I need another one in front of each server such that it looks like:

```
Client Request ----> Nginx (Reverse-Proxy / Load-Balancer)
                        |
                       /|\                           
                      | | `-> Nginx + App. Server I.   10.128.xxx.yy1:8080 # Our example
                      |  `--> Nginx + App. Server II.  10.128.xxx.yy2:8080
                       `----> ..
```

If Nginx is an HTTP server, and Gunicorn is an HTTP server, why would I need another Nginx server in front of each App Server? It seems redundant.

And if I don't need another Nginx server in front of each Gunicorn server, how do I set up the Gunicorn server with systemd such that it can stand alone?

**Edit:**

I was curious as to why the binding to a physical port was working, but the socket wasn't, so I ran gunicorn status and got errors:

```
kyle@ubuntu-512mb-tor1-01-app:~/do_app_one$ . venv/bin/activate
(venv) kyle@ubuntu-512mb-tor1-01-app:~/do_app_one$ gunicorn status
[2016-12-03 20:19:49 +0000] [11050] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2016-12-03 20:19:49 +0000] [11050] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (11050)
[2016-12-03 20:19:49 +0000] [11050] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-12-03 20:19:49 +0000] [11053] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11053
[2016-12-03 20:19:49 +0000] [11053] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kyle/do_app_one/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/kyle/do_app_one/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/kyle/do_app_one/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/kyle/do_app_one/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/kyle/do_app_one/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/kyle/do_app_one/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/kyle/do_app_one/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named 'status'
[2016-12-03 20:19:49 +0000] [11053] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11053)
[2016-12-03 20:19:49 +0000] [11050] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2016-12-03 20:19:49 +0000] [11050] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Still not sure how to fix the problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is to just bind Gunicorn to a port instead of a unix socket. I'm not too sure about the details, but unix sockets can only be used within a local network according to:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91774/performance-of-unix-sockets-vs-tcp-ports

So when I changed the gunicorn.service file ExecStart line to:

```
ExecStart=/home/kyle/do_app_one/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 do_app_one.wsgi:application
```

I was able to access the server by itself, and connect it to my Nginx server that was on a different IP.